# open-office bullet point, style when importing html

Tags: automation, openoffice.org

I am importing html in to open office and converting it to odt( using PyODConverter), then using zip to replace the style sheet style.xml.

I am having problems with the spacing of the bullet lists, but can not change it. Bullet lists have a style of Text Body, so if I change it all the paragraphs change as well.

Is there a way to make bullet lists a different style, automatically, on import (from html)?
Or to set a style that applies only to Text Body that is a bullet list?

I can edit style.xml if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used conditional formatting.

- Load doc as an odt (loading a html does not work: I could not find the options*).
- Add new formats for what you want, based on text body (or what ever format the section is already in).
- Modify text body format, select condition*, and link numbering levels to your new styles.

Then save the file and extract the style.xml, using zip, for use latter.